# How to compare two fields in QueryBuilder?

Tags: axapta, query-builder, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, select-query

I'm using **QueryBuilder**.
I want to select all record in *VendTable* having two equal fields.

My code is looklike this:

```
QueryBuildDataSource qbds;
QueryRun        queryRun;

qbds= queryRun.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(VendTable));
qbds.addRange(fieldNum(VendTable, BirthDate))
.value(strFmt('%1 == %2',strFmt("%1.%2",qbds.name(), fieldStr(VendTable,BirthDate)) ,strFmt("%1.%2", qbds.name(),fieldStr(VendTable,FieldTransDate))));
```

On *Debug* I see thie query value:

> SELECT * FROM VendTable(VendTable_1) WHERE ((BirthDate = {ts '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'}))

But not work, I would like to create this query :

```
select vendTable
 where vendTable.BirthDate== vendTable.FieldTransDate;
```

SELECT * FROM VendTable(VendTable_1) WHERE ((BirthDate = FieldTransDate))

I want to compare the Fields on same Table BirthDate == FieldTransDate

How I can make the query shown above by QueryBuilder ?

Thanks,
enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not use the correct syntax for a [query expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/aa893981.aspx). Remember the parentheses:

```cs
qbds.addRange(fieldNum(VendTable, BirthDate))
    .value(strFmt('(%1 == %2)',
                  strFmt("%1.%2", qbds.name(), fieldStr(VendTable, BirthDate)),
                  strFmt("%1.%2", qbds.name(), fieldStr(VendTable, TransDate))));
```